# While inserting data into the oracle database code automatically generate value 0 for id using MVC with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

While inserting data into the Oracle database code automatically generate value 0 for id using MVC with entity framework.How to solve this.

```
public ActionResult AddNewNode(AddNode model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (Nspira_DBContext entity = new Nspira_DBContext())
                    {
                        TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS hierarchyDetail = new TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS()
                        {

                            NAME = model.NodeName,
                            PID = model.ParentName,
                        };

                        entity.TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS.Add(hierarchyDetail);
                        entity.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

[image]
My table has ID, NAME and PID column.While inserting query in the database means it generated the sequence number.While inserting data through code means It doesn't create the sequence.It fetches value as 0 automatically.How to solve this.

How to solve this.Please, anyone, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   using (Nspira_DBContext entity = new Nspira_DBContext())
                   {

                       int objid = entity.TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS.Max(p => p.ID);
                       TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS hierarchyDetail = new TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS()
                       {
                           ID = objid + 1,
                          NAME = model.NodeName,
                           PID = model.ParentName,
                       };

                       entity.TBL_ACCESSRIGHTS.Add(hierarchyDetail);
                       entity.SaveChanges();
                   }
                   return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
               }
           }
```

please try  this